# Incorrect localized Hebrew date on iOS and watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, localization, watchos, hebrew

I’m working on a date/time app that does things that Apple didn’t build into its OSs and bundled applications.

I’m leveraging built-in classes like `Date` and `DateFormatter` for certain parts, and I’m getting some odd results for dates on the Hebrew calendar localized in Hebrew.

If I request the standard `full`, `long`, `medium`, and `short` formats, everything is fine. But when I supply a template for DateFormatter to use, something weird happens.

[image]

That middle row in the three-date complication (containing the date on the Gregorian, Hebrew, and Muslim calendars), is wrong.

It should be `יום א׳, ז׳ בחשון תשפ״א`, because the convention is for Hebrew dates in Hebrew to use Hebrew numerals.

The relevant code that produces the Hebrew date:

We first start with setting the locale and time zone of our specialized Hebrew and Islamic calendar class’s date formatter.

```
    if localeIdentifier == "" {
        self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    } else {
        self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier)
    }
    self.dateFormatter.timeZone = timeZone
```

After some code dealing with generating the correct time (not really used in a complication), we set the `DateFormatter`’s dateStyle or date format based one the value of an enum (“majorDateFormat”); if we are supposed to use a template (case .localizedLDML), we use a specific string (“dateGeekFormat”) as the template.

In this case, I have specified a format with weekday, day, month, and year narrow enough to squeeze into a watchOS complication without losing information. We then generate the date string for the Date fixedNow.

```
   switch majorDateFormat {
    case .localizedLDML:
        let dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate:dateGeekFormat, options: 0, locale: self.dateFormatter.locale)!
        self.dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(dateFormat)

    case .none:
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none

    case .full:
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full

    case .long:
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long

    case .medium:
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium

    case .short:
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

    default:
        self.dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
    } // switch majorDateFormat

    let dateString = self.dateFormatter.string(from: fixedNow)
```

Now the weird things are:

1. For the Islamic calendar in Arabic, Arabic numerals are correctly produced.
2. This code actually used to correctly work for the Hebrew calendar in Hebrew.

I had no problems with this on `watchOS 5` on my old series 0 Apple Watch, but I recently upgraded to an Apple Watch SE running `watchOS 7` and discovered this problem.

Has anyone else seen such a problem before? Is this a bug on Apple’s part, or is there something I’ve missed?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can produce "יום א׳, ז׳ בחשון תשפ״א"

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .hebrew)
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "he")
formatter.dateStyle = .short // must come before date format below         
formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("c dd MMMM yyyy")

print(formatter.string(from: Date())) // יום א׳, ז׳ בחשון תשפ״א
```

Comment: @אהרןאדלמן make sure that `dateStyle` is set before `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`.